# Can't remove UILabel from it's superview

Tags: ios, swift

I am facing a problem. I have a class which adds UILabel to some other view.

That's the class:

```
    class noDataColor{

        let errLabel = UILabel()

        func addNoDataLabel(_ tableView:UITableView, text:String, color: UIColor){

        //Err label

        self.errLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 15, y: 20, width: tableView.bounds.width, height: 60)
        self.errLabel.textColor = color
        self.errLabel.text = text
        self.errLabel.isHidden = false
        tableView.addSubview(self.errLabel)
        print("errLabelFrame\(errLabel.frame)") //Prints normal frame
}

    func removeNoDataLabelColor(){
        //Err label
            print("Executed")
            errLabel.isHidden = true
            errLabel.removeFromSuperview()
            errLabel.textColor = UIColor.clear
            print("errLabelFrame\(errLabel.frame)") //Prints (0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0)
        }
    }
```

And then I add my errLabel using this line (everything works fine and my label is added):

```
noDataColor().addNoDataLabel(self.tableView, text: errorMessage!, color: .white)
```

But here comes my problem, because this line does nothing:

```
noDataColor().removeNoDataLabelColor()
```

,even though it prints `"Executed"`.

**My question is:** How can I remove my errLabel without using delegates.

**Note:** I use those lines in different class than `noDataColor` class.

Thank you :)

Comment: Can you try printing print("addNoDataLabel  Executed") to your addNoDataLabel method and check how many time it gets called?
I am pretty sure you are calling addNoDataLabel multiple times

Comment: why are you using **self.** ... ?

Comment: Gets called only once :/

Comment: Every time you call `noDataColor()` it creates a new instance of your class with its own `errLabel`.  Whatever is creating the first instance needs to hold a reference to it and call `removeNoDataLabelColor()` on that reference.

Comment: right Dan has explained the problem.  add an initializer that explicitly initializes errLabel, and add a print statement inside it.  fiurthermore, I would just make it an optional .. UIView? .. and only initialize it inside addNoDataLabel.

Comment: It is weird, because I am using very similar class to show UIActivityIndicator (loading) and it works without a problem. I have also tried to put that errLabel to UIView and remove that UIView, but did not work either :/

Comment: are you sure that `errLabel` at the moment when `removeNoDataLabelColor()` executed not nil?

Comment: `UITableView` doesn't work very well with custom subviews. Never add subviews to a table view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you call `noDataColor()`you create a new instance of your class.

```
noDataColor().addNoDataLabel(self.tableView, text: errorMessage!, color: .white)
noDataColor().removeNoDataLabelColor()
```

The second line creates a new instance of the `noDataColor` which has never had it's `addNoDataLabel(_, text:, color:)`called. You need to keep a reference of you class around:

```
let noDataColor = noDataColor()
noDataColor.addNoDataLabel(self.tableView, text: errorMessage!, color: .white)
noDataColor.removeNoDataLabelColor()
```

As you can see you need to call the methods on the same object.